# multiple gaussian fit with bounds (astropy)

Tags: python, gaussian, astropy

I want to do a multiple Gaussian Fit. There are two questions here,

1. Is it ok that I set g1, g2 and g3 and then add up them all to get g?
2. How to use bounds to set up limits on the value of amplitude, mean and stddev? Or does any one know how to set up a range for the three values?

My code is:

```
from astropy.modeling.models import Gaussian1D
from astropy.modeling import fitting

np.random.seed(0)
x = x_k
y = y_k
y += np.random.normal(0., 0.2, x.shape)
g1 = Gaussian1D(amplitude=8, mean=-3000, stddev=2000)
g1.bounding_box.amplitude = (5, 10) #I am not sure this format is right because I cannot find an example in astropy
g1.bounding_box.mean = (-4000,-1000)
g2 = Gaussian1D(amplitude=10, mean=0, stddev=2500)
g2.bounding_box.amplitude = (5, 10)
g3 = Gaussian1D(amplitude=8, mean=3000, stddev=2000)
g3.bounding_box.amplitude = (5, 10)
fit_g = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
g = fit_g(g1+g2+g3, x, y)
```

and the result is:

```
g # I input
<CompoundModel9(amplitude_0=5.253073136928387, mean_0=-5457.846704763921, stddev_0=2575.658823137438, amplitude_1=9.341542274082872, mean_1=576.199390319498, stddev_1=4435.00571482351, amplitude_2=4.398784254758611, mean_2=5597.341719866905, stddev_2=1625.151756962933)>
```

Obviously it doesn't work. What is the matter?

Comment: The [Gaussian1D](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.functional_models.Gaussian1D.html#gaussian1d) documentation suggests that the `bounds` attribute should be used, which is a dict with parameter names as keys, and can be set to a 2-element list of [low, high]. Not having tried myself, see if this works: `g1.bounds['mean'] = [-4000, 4000]` etc.

Comment: The `bounding_box` attribute is different. From the [documentaion](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/bounding-boxes.html): " a bounding_box attribute [...] can be used to set the limits over which the model is significant." Thus, it's rather a soft limit, and relates to the *input* data, not the model parameters.

Comment: (cont.) The bounding_box attribute can be set to a tuple of tuples, with the outer tuple length equal to the dimension of the model (here, 1), and the inner tuples of length 2. See [examples in the documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.Model.html#astropy.modeling.Model.bounding_box).

Comment: Your code can not be processed without the `x_k, y_k` data.